# MapBox - one world copy on screen on high resolution screens

Tags: leaflet, mapbox

In my MapBox application, using MapBox.js Map is being displayed on full page (width:100%,height:100%). Map starts using following code snippet

```
L.mapbox.accessToken = accessToken;
map = L.mapbox.map('basicMap', 'mapbox.streets',
    {
        minZoom: 2,
        maxZoom: 17,
        attributionControl: false,
        worldCopyJump: true,
        zoomControl: false
    }).setView([35, 0], 2);
```

On large screens, World copies repeat itself (means USA and Australia comes twice from Left and right side). I Want to repeat world copies (worldCopyJump: true) BUT one copy at a time according to screens Like bounding box of [65,-100],[-65,100]

Tried options :
1) fitWorld : http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.2.0.html#map-fitworld

map.fitWorld().zoomIn();

2) fitBounds : http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.2.0.html#map-fitbounds

map.fitBounds([[
     65.958984,
     -100.353521
    ], [
     -65.50585,
     100.615985
    ]]);

But couldn't match the exact requirement. Any one has any idea, working solution for large and small desktop screens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quick & dirty: Use a bigger value for the `minZoom` option of the `L.Map`.

A bit more refined: on the `resize` event of your `map`, [`unproject()`](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.2.0.html#map-unproject) the top-left and bottom-right corners of the map container (in pixels) at minimum zoom, calculate if they would span more than 360 degrees of longitude, calculate how many times they would do so, apply [`getScaleZoom()`](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.2.0.html#map-getscalezoom) with that ratio, set `minZoom` to that number.

Be aware of the [`zoomSnap`](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.2.0.html#map-zoomsnap) option too, if you're thinking of using a non-integer value for `minZoom`.